# Two different imports, why does one not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When importing the `SMTPHandler`, why does this approach work:

```
>>> from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
# <class 'logging.handlers.SMTPHandler'>
```

But this one does not?

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.handlers.SMTPHandler
# AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'handlers'
```

Often the second approach does work, but I'm wondering for the `logging` module why that doesn't import down the dot path?